# jquery selectpicker not working for dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used following library to design select box

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```

Its working fine for first div .if i generate item from dynamically using jquery then its not showing

```
$('#add_new_repair').click(function(){

 i++;

var mydata='<div class="item form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Model Parts Name <span class="required">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <input id="brand_name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" placeholder="Model Name e.g Nokia 1100" required="required" type="text"> </div> <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="remove_repair_'+i+'" onclick="removeRow(this);> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"> </span>Remove</button> </div> </div> <div class="item form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Model Parts Price <span class="required">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <input id="brand_name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" placeholder="Price" required="required" type="text"> </div> </div> <div class="item form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Model Parts Warrenty<span class="required">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <select id="basic" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" data-live-search="true"> <option value="AK" selected>---Select--</option> <option value="ss">Alaska</option> <option value="HI">Nokia</option> <option value="CA">Motorolla</option> <option value="NV">Samsung</option> <option value="OR">Oregon</option> <option value="WA">Washington</option> <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> <option value="CO">Colorado</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="item form-group"> <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Model Image <span class="required">*</span> </label> <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> <input type="file" id="input03" class="form-control"> </div> </div> <div class="ln_solid"></div>';
   var content = '<select class="pincode"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
 $("#dynamic_data").append(mydata);


});
```

Comment: `$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');` use this to render selectpicker after you append `content ` to `dynamic_data`

Comment: @Curiousdev.Thanks working fine now.please add answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are dynamicaly generating select list so after appending content you have to forcefully render `selectpicker` for dynamically generated select list by following below line

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, for every change inside html at selectpicker you need to call refresh function. I think that is better than render.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: it'll work but basically what "refresh" is for to manipulate the select list and than update the UI as per our manipulation this works like a charm no offend but i don't recommend this to use instead `render` is force a re-render of the bootstrap-select which has been dynamically added

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `on` or dynamically created elements

```
$(document).on('click','#add_new_repair',function(){

// your code here

})
```

Comment: @ameya.Thanks but not working.other input boxes are generating .select box not showing

Comment: @ameya: Jquerys "$('#add_new_repair').click(function(){" means the same.. ;)

Comment: other input boxes are generating .select box not showing.no error

Comment: even i am using http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/ this library to design file upload. here i am getting browse button but deisng not showing

Comment: @J.Sadi I think they are not. as per my knowledge. if you are adding elements after DOM is loaded then you have to handle their click events using `.on`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande.Thanks for the answer. for me Curiousdev answer helped me.any way.thanks.i will vote you